# How to make a pie chart froma field in the database?

Tags: javascript, css, codeigniter

I have 3 categories in this table field, the categories are "not yet, currently, done".

[image]

I want to make a pie chart.

This is my model:

```
public function select_by_status() {
        $sql = "SELECT COUNT(status_laporan) AS jml FROM tp4d GROUP BY status_laporan ORDER BY jml";

        $data = $this->db->query($sql);

        return $data->row();
    }
```

this my controller to show in the pie chart,

```
//untuk statistik laporan
        $laporan                = $this->M_laporan->select_all();
        $index = 0;
        foreach ($laporan as $value) {
            $color = '#' .$rand[rand(0,15)] .$rand[rand(0,15)] .$rand[rand(0,15)] .$rand[rand(0,15)] .$rand[rand(0,15)] .$rand[rand(0,15)];

            $laporan_status = $this->M_laporan->select_by_status();

            $data_laporan[$index]['value'] = $laporan_status->jml;
            $data_laporan[$index]['color'] = $color;
            $data_laporan[$index]['highlight'] = $color;
            $data_laporan[$index]['label'] = $value->status_laporan;

            $index++;
        }
$data['data_laporan'] = json_encode($data_laporan);
```

This is my view:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="box box-primary">
      <div class="box-header with-border">
        <i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i>
        <h3 class="box-title">Statistik <small>Data Status Laporan</small></h3>

        <div class="box-tools pull-right">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="box-body">
        <canvas id="data-laporan" style="height:250px"></canvas>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this is my script for the pie chart:

```
var pieChartCanvas = $("#data-laporan").get(0).getContext("2d");
  var pieChart = new Chart(pieChartCanvas);
  var PieData = <?php echo $data_laporan; ?>;

  var pieOptions = {
    segmentShowStroke: true,
    segmentStrokeColor: "#fff",
    segmentStrokeWidth: 2,
    percentageInnerCutout: 50,
    animationSteps: 100,
    animationEasing: "easeOutBounce",
    animateRotate: true,
    animateScale: false,
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: true,
    legendTemplate: "<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<segments.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"background-color:<%=segments[i].fillColor%>\"></span><%if(segments[i].label){%><%=segments[i].label%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>"
  };

  pieChart.Doughnut(PieData, pieOptions);
```

The problem is that in every part of the chart that is displayed, all the contents are the same, in my database that has a status there are no 2 records while completing 1 record but on the pie chart it looks the same, all like this:

[image]

[image]

How can the statistics be the same as the data in the database?

Comment: you can follow canvasjs. take a look at this:
https://canvasjs.com/html5-javascript-doughnut-chart/

Comment: `var PieData = <?php echo $data_laporan; ?>;` what is the return on this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the data should be an object in JSON format.

You can encode an object to JSON using `json_encode($your_object)`, then pass it onto the JavaScript.

Comment: i have do that, but still the same

Comment: is there an error on the console?

what is the return on

`<?php echo $data_laporan; ?>`